# Binding IPs to non-root users

Tags: ubuntu, debian, iptables, ip

I want to bind IPs to non-root users so that all outgoing applications will use that IP for the user. I have this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m owner --uid-owner xxx -j SNAT --to-source xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

But when I when I do check iptables:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
iptables -t nat -L
```

to see the rules you've added, since your commands are in the `nat` table, not the default `filter` table:

```
$ man iptables
..snip..
  --table   -t table    table to manipulate (default: `filter')
```

which is why `iptables -L` shows up blank, because you have no rules in your `filter` table.